# eclipse error of "Error occurred during initialization of VM "

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Eclipse project, which got the following error message after running

[image]

The "classpath" setting in "run configurations" is shown as follows

[image]

The "build path" setting is shown as follows:

[image]

Comment: why you added `jre/bin` folder to classpath ??

Comment: Then what should I add instead? just jre, thanks.

Comment: only include the JRE Sysytem library included by the eclipse when creation of project

Comment: I delete the java\jre7 from teh "build path" setting. But the problem is still there. How to modify the "classpath" setting in the "run configuration". Thanks. Or how to make it point to the JRE system included by the eclipse as you said.

Comment: First remove the `bin` folder from BuildPath. In `classpath` under `Run Configuration`, select on the `Bootstrap Entries` and at Right button click `Restore Default Entries`. This should put the default JRE System library by replacing the `bin` folder

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're using System JRE instead of JDK.

From the "Libraries" tab, select "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7] > choose Edit > then from popup window > Execution Environment choose JDK environment, eg JavaSE-1.6 (jdk1.6.0_32)